# Unable to connect IdPop3 to IdPop3Server via SSL

Tags: delphi, email, ssl, indy, pop3

I have a `TIdPop3Server` in one application that has a `IdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL1` attached to it and retrieves emails and sends them to a `TIdPop3` client in another application (having `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` attached to it). Everything's fine when the connections are made insecure using port 110. But when I try to use `SSL` connection through port 995 I get error `Connection Closed Gracefully` after connect attemp from the client fails. This is my `Pop3SeverOnConnect` event :

```
procedure TMainForm.Pop3ServerConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  if (AContext.Connection.IOHandler is TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase) then
    TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase(AContext.Connection.IOHandler).PassThrough :=
    (AContext.Binding.Port <> 995);
  showmessage('SSL connection made!');
end;
```

And this is the client-side :

```
procedure TMainForm.btnCheckMailBoxClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.PassThrough := False;
  POP3Client.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1;
  with POP3Client do begin
    AuthType := patUserPass;
    Host := myHost;
    UserName := myUserName;
    Password := myPass;
    Port := myPort;
  end;
  try
    POP3Client.Connect;  
  Except on e : Exception do 
    showmessage('error=' + e.Message);
  end;
  // code for retrieving message data 
end;
```

And I always get an exception from `Pop3Client.Connect` like I've already mentioned above (The message `SSL connection made!` in the server application never shows up). If I use however another mail client like for example `Mozilla Thunderbird` I achieve a successful SSL connection for port 995. So the problem should be somewhere in the client's procedure but who knows - that's why I'm asking you guys for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your client code, you need to set the `TIdPOP3.UseTLS` property instead of the `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.PassThrough` property directly, eg:

```
procedure TMainForm.btnCheckMailBoxClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with POP3Client do
  begin
    IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1;
    AuthType := patUserPass;
    UseTLS := utUseImplicitTLS; // <-- here
    Host := myHost;
    UserName := myUserName;
    Password := myPass;
    Port := myPort;
  end;
  try
    POP3Client.Connect;  
    try
      // code for retrieving message data 
    finally
      POP3Client.Disconnect;  
    end;
  except
    on e : Exception do 
      ShowMessage('error=' + e.Message);
  end;
end;
```

In your server code, you need to get rid of the `ShowMessage()`.  `TIdPOP3Server` is multi-threaded, the `OnConnect` event is fired in the context of a worker thread, and `ShowMessage()` is not thread-safe.  If you must display a popup message, use `Windows.MessageBox()` instead.

Comment: So ``UseTLS := utUseImplicitTLS`` makes the difference. Thanks, again Remy :)